# Limitar cantidad de registros ingresados en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

He realizado un módulo de matricula de cursos usando PHP y MYSQL donde hay un limite de vacantes disponibles.

La validación de las vacantes lo hago mediante MySQL en el momento en que el usuario selecciona el curso pero me ha pasado que a veces la cantidad de matriculados excede en uno o dos a la cantidad de vacantes que se asigno.

He realizado algunas pruebas en cuanto al funcionamiento de módulo y me di cuenta que si dos usuarios seleccionan el curso al mismo tiempo llegan a ocupar esa vacante a pesar de que solo hay una disponible.

Espero me puedan ayudar encontrar la forma de evitar que ingresen mas usuarios de vacantes ya asignadas.

```
DECLARE _validate int;
DECLARE _permitir int;
DECLARE _repetido int;
    
    SET _validate = (SELECT ft_verifVacantesMaximas(_codCurso));
    
    SET _permitir=(SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT codCurso,secCurso,vacPermitido,vacMaximo,ft_obtenerMatriculados(codCurso, secCurso) as matriculados FROM vacantes WHERE codCurso=_codCurso AND secCurso=_secCurso) i
WHERE if(_validate=1,i.vacMaximo>i.matriculados,i.vacPermitido>i.matriculados));

    IF(_permitir>0) THEN
        SET _repetido=(SELECT count(*) FROM matricula_temporal WHERE codAlumno=_codAlumno and codCurso=_codCurso);
        IF(_repetido>0)THEN
            SELECT "Curso ya matriculado" as error;
        ELSE
            INSERT matricula_temporal(codAlumno,codCurso,secCurso) VALUES (_codAlumno,_codCurso,_secCurso);
            SELECT "Registrado" as res;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        SELECT "Sin vacantes" as error;
    END IF;
```

Comment: Hola AnderFeler, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: podrias colocar el codigo de la funcion `ft_verifVacantesMaximas` y que se supone que hace `_permitir` o que intentas que haga??

Comment: Asumo que haces la validación cuando el usuario empieza a llenar el formulario y es por esa razón que si hay mas dos o mas usuarios llenando el formulario al mismo tiempo se pueden saltar la validación. Tengo en mente un par de opciones y te las enumero en el siguiente comentario...

Comment: La primera es validar justo antes de hacer el `insert` en la BD y le retornas un mensaje al usuario indicando que no se pudo registrar la solicitud porque se excedió el número de vacantes mientras llenaba el formulario. La segunda y la más efectiva para la experiencia de usuario es usar asincronismo con `ajax` o `fetch` para que reserves el cupo en la BD. Luego, haces la validación para mostrarle el mensaje al usuario en tiempo real al seleccionar el curso, si es que ya no hay vacantes disponibles.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, de hecho la validación la hago en el procedimiento almacenado de MYSQL justo antes de insertar el curso.